# Levy's isoperimetric inequality for sphere

Tags: isoperimetric-problems, mg.metric-geometry, measure-concentration, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

Let me recall subj:

If $s>0$, $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, $|A|=|B|$ ($|\cdot|$ stands for the Lebesgue measure on the sphere) and $B$ is a cup $B=\{ (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{S}^n, x_n\leq t \}$ (for some $t\in [-1,1]$), then $|A_s|\geq |B_s|$, where $A_s$ means $s$-neighborhood of the set.

It leads to measure concentration inequalities for the sphere and so has numerous applications. So I guess that Levy's initial proof was simplified, maybe not once. What is the easiest proof of the inequality and where to read it?

Comment: I don't know if the original proof by Levy can be considered a full proof by today's standards, but it sure looks simple enough: https://archive.org/stream/leconsdanalysefo00levyrich#page/n281/mode/2up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest and most amazing proof (in my opinion) is by Steiner symmetrization around half of a great circle.  Given $A$, and given a half great circle $\gamma$, rotate the sphere so that $\gamma$ is a meridian arc.  Then for each latitude sphere $H$, you can replace $A \cap H$ by the spherical cap in $H$ centered at $H \cap \gamma$.  Let $A'$ be the result.  Then it is not hard to show that $|A'_s| \le |A_s|$ for all $s > 0$; in fact even each $|A'_s \cap H| \le |A_s \cap H|$.  And you can show that you can pick a sequence of half great circles such that $A$ converges to $B$ under symmetrization, and that some of the inequalities are strict unless $A$ is congruent to $B$.

Of course this is just an outline, but it is an accurate summary (I hope) of the Steiner symmetrization argument.  It also works in Euclidean or hyperbolic space using a line rather than half of a line.

Comment: $|A'_s\cap H|\leq A_s\cap H$ is induction propose if we use induction on dimension, right?

Comment: ah, no, $A_s\cap H$ does not depend only on $A\cap H$, but on close lattitudes too...

Comment: Yes, it's a proof by induction, even though $A_s \cap H$ depends on nearby latitudes.

Comment: Ah, for $A'$ it depend only on one latitude (though maybe different from $H$), so here everything is OK. It remains to show that a sequence of symmetrizations converge to a hat, It should be standard.

Comment: Convergence is based on the fact that the circumradius of $A$ can only go down under symmetrization.  Moreover, if you do enough symmetrizations, it does go down unless $A$ is a spherical cap.


Comment: Has this proof been published somewhere? I know two proofs that rely on Steiner symmetrization, one by [Dinghas](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=33076) and one by [Tippe](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=157290) whose descriptions sound considerably more complicated than the outline you have given.

Comment: Although it's been a long time, I think I learned it from [Figiel, Lindenstrauss, Milman](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889965).  I'm also not sure whether this proof is essentially different from the ones that you have seen.  It may mainly be a matter of abbreviated vs detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A different symmetrization-based proof is given in [this review article](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~gideon/papers/concentrationNov19.ps) by Schechtman (pp. 7-8); see the previous page for references.

Comment: Sorry, is a link OK? It downloads some file of 1.1kb size.

Comment: It's a PostScript file. If you have a Mac and double-click on the file, it will automatically be converted into a PDF file. For Windows, it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: I may read .ps files, but not of 1kb size

Comment: The .ps file is actually 700kB.  The link works for me, on two different computers.